# How much are breeding odds increased for level 15+ dragons?

Tags: dragonvale

With the v1.13.0 update, level 15+ dragons now have increased breeding odds.

> Better breeding odds for level 15+ dragons!

How much have the odds increased?  Does the increase scale with increased level in the range from 15 - 20, or is it a flat increase?  To which types of dragons does the increase apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What are the Odds?**
The odds increase does not seem to be specifically listed anywhere, but I think it is safe to assume for the moment that it is something small, on the order of 5% - similar to the EBI.  I'll update if more details become available.

**Does it scale?**

Based on the [DragonVale Wiki](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Shrines), the increase scales with level.

> Dragons at level 15 and higher give better odds in breeding "rare" dragons; the odds increase as the level increases.

**Which dragons are affected?**

Also per a wiki admin in that article, in response to the question of which dragons this boost applies to:

> BFS doesn't make that clear. Most Epics are generally rare, but they don't really define exactly what they mean by it.