# How does breeding time affect the outcome of the species of dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

On DragonVale Breeding Guide, the breeding times affects the type of dragon that will be produced. Say, how would I keep the dragons breeding for 32 hours? Or 24 hours? And how does time affect it?!

Answer (score 3):

You've got it backwards.

What type of dragon that winds up getting bred determines how long the two parents will be at it.

The only way to even *slightly* influence the outcome is by obtaining the [Epic Breeding Island](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Epic_Breeding_Island), which has a higher chance of breeding rare dragons according to its wiki entry.

See the Dragonvale Breeding Wikia page for more details than rightfully fit in this answer, and use the [Breeding Sandbox](http://www.2084.org/dragonvale/breeding-sandbox/) to puzzle out how to maximize your chances to get the dragon you want.

**ETA**: Recently, an update increased the chance of level 15 and 20 dragons to breed rares, but as mentioned in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106255/how-much-are-breeding-odds-increased-for-level-15-dragons) people are still trying to determine how much. Statistics are a slow process. :)

Comment: Also, it's not something you can control. You get what you get, and there's no real way of impacting the outcome.

Comment: @Shadur You may have missed the recent update, but dragon levels above level 15 also affect the odds of breeding rare dragons.  We're still [puzzling out](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106255/how-much-are-breeding-odds-increased-for-level-15-dragons) how much it affects odds, but I believe it is fairly significant with level 20s (based on my experience).