# How do you breed a Diamond Dragon in Dragonvale?

Tags: dragonvale

I can't seem to find out how to breed a diamond dragon in Dragonvale. I've tried quite a few combos in the Epic Breeding Island, but none work for me. Anyone know a confirmed combo? I've heard it's Mine and Ice, but it doesn't work. Do they need to be a certain level? I really need a gemstone dragon.

Comment: I play on iOS, but I've heard reports from Android users that you need to load an update to the game in order to get the Aquamarine from March to switch over to Diamond in the shop.  It's not clear to me whether this effects your odds of breeding, but it may.  Trying checking for updates to the game.

Comment: @EBongo Oh thank goodness you informed me of that; I was worried!

Comment: Getting this dragon is really **hard**.

Comment: It is indeed.  It's killing my OCD need to have them all.  I suppose it could be a play on their part to suck some more dollars out of us.  But at that price I'm not buying...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I can confirm](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/posts/2065) that the combo you're looking for is: **Ice + Mine**.  Since this is a Gemstone dragon, it is not obvious that this is the pair you need.  Another consequence of it being a Gemstone is that this is the only possible pairing, and you can not breed more by having two.  Your dragons don't need to be any special level, but if they are over 15 [you have a better chance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106255/how-much-are-breeding-odds-increased-for-level-15-dragons).  Also, the EBI will give you [slightly better chances](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Epic_Breeding_Island) than the breeding cave, so if you are spending gems to speed up breeding, I recommend prioritizing the EBI.

Personally, I've found this one quite hard, perhaps the hardest of the Gemstones (diamond pun for you :) ).  With the long fail times of Quicksilver, Steel, Silver, and Platinum, you end up waiting a long time with each failed attempt.  The month is still early, so keep calm and breed on.

Comment: I got pretty fortunate with mine. Platinum > Silver > Diamond. Still, I hated having my island occupied for 96 hours of bad luck.

Answer (score 1):

Iceberg dragon and mine worked first time for me..

Comment: Hi Emma, could you elaborate a little more your answer?

Comment: Emma, your answer is great. But next time when you answer a question, make sure to detail it and give it a little more _unph_, you get more vote-ups and reputation!

Comment: Hi Emma, I think you confused Iceberg with Ice.  There is only one combo for this dragon, and it is Ice + Mine.

Answer (score 1):

Google dragonvale sandbox and use that to find all dragon breed combos. You can put in 2 dragons and get the results possible — or viceversa. It is awesome to say the least and I recommend it to anyone who plays it.

Comment: Cool! I'll try that.